# Pointer assignment causing program to stall

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, freeze

This is really getting me, I have a program that I'm adding some additional features too, and one thing that I'm trying to do is implement a linked list. First, some code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "host.h"
#include "misc.h"
#include "machine.h"

struct miss_pile{
  md_addr_t tag;
  unsigned int isCon;
  char block_type;
  char culprit_type;
  struct miss_pile * next;

}*head=0, *linkPtr, *tail=NULL, *newLink;
typedef struct miss_pile mp;

void add_beg(md_addr_t new_tag/*int new_tag*/, char blk_type, char evicter_type){

  newLink = (mp *)malloc(sizeof(mp));
  newLink->tag = new_tag;
  newLink->block_type = blk_type;
  newLink->culprit_type = evicter_type; 
  newLink->isCon = 0;

if (head == NULL){
     head=newLink;
     head->next=NULL;
     head->tag = new_tag;
     head->block_type = blk_type;
     head->culprit_type = evicter_type;
     head->isCon=0; 
  }
 else if (head != NULL)
  {
    newLink->next=head;
    head = newLink;
  }
}
```

I've determined that this line is where the program seems to stop

`head=newLink;`

Once I exclude this code, the program runs fine, but of course its pretty essential code. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

A few things to note, the processor stays at 100% while the program "sits". Also, the program I'm adding the list to is SimpleScalar's "sim-cache" simulator.

Comment: What system are you running on? I would try running it in a debugger, like gdb on linux, or in the builtin Visual Studio one on Windows. For GDB compile your program with the -g flag. There are plenty of tutorials on gdb, so I won't bore you with the details.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 in a virtual machine. Running gdb provides some usefull information, it seems to be getting stuck in some of my list search loops, I'll double check them and possibly post them. Could this just be a time intensive task? This list is very likely to reach hundreds of thousands. But still, limiting the number of instructions in simplescalar, which should keep the list short, has no effect.

Comment: I have a feeling that someone will come in soon and say "don't cast the result of `malloc()`" :-)

Comment: Complete and utter aside, but you don't need to check that `head != NULL` in your else clause.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you can simplify your function like this :

```
void add_beg(md_addr_t new_tag/*int new_tag*/, char blk_type, char evicter_type){

    newLink = (mp *)malloc(sizeof(mp));
    newLink->tag = new_tag;
    newLink->block_type = blk_type;
    newLink->culprit_type = evicter_type; 
    newLink->isCon = 0;
    /* on the first call, head is NULL, and it's exactly what we want */
    newLink->next = head;
    /* then head point to the new element */
    head = newLink;
}
```

Secondly, I'm pretty sure that your bug is coming from somewhere else in your code, may be some other functions that interact with your global variable *head* ? Or it might be anything else of course :)

Comment: Ahhh, you sir are correct, the issue lay elsewhere in my code. I had a poorly designed search loop;                                   linkPtr = head;
    while (linkPtr!=NULL)
     {
     if(linkPtr->tag != fnd_tag)
      {linkPtr=linkPtr->next;}
     else{break;}
     }